# How can I safely replace a light fixture above a stairwell?

Tags: light-fixture, safety, stairs, ladder

In my 1911 home, there is a stairwell that has a 180 degree turn with a landing, and there is a light fixture directly overhead (centered over the railing) that I would like to replace with a pendant light. When I'm standing directly below it (halfway up the second flight of steps) the ceiling is about 3 feet out of my reach. I imagine there is some standard approach to doing this type of work (someone installed that light in the 1950's).

How can I get a stable ladder or platform in place to safely work on that fixture?

The second story ceiling is 8 feet 6 inches above the floor, as shown in this photo:

[image: View of fixture from second floor]

On the other side of the railing, the distance from the fixture to the closest step on the first flight is about 15 feet:

[image: View of fixture from first floor (cat for scale)]

This is what I intend to replace the fixture with:

[image: Hunter Lighting Reed Rattan Black 1-Light Outdoor Pendant Light]

Comment: There are ladders that work great in stairwells adjustable A-frame type.   Gorilla and little giant are two popular brands.

Comment: the builders probably used a scaffold

Comment: can you get above the ceiling?

Comment: @jsotola There is currently no attic access (this is also on my TODO list).

Comment: @Jasen The house was originally gas-lit, so the fixture would have been installed at a later date.

Comment: Cat: "I don't care what they suggest!  I'm out of here until this is over!"

Comment: Here's what I would do: 1) Look at scaffold rental.  Decide life's too short. 2)  Get quotes from electricians to do it.  Decide I'd rather use the money for a vacation.  3) Leave the old fixture there.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [this type of ladder](https://www.littlegiantladder.com/collections/home-bestselling-ladders/products/velocity). It allows for a configuration like this on a staircase:

[image: ladder]

Here is [another option](https://smile.amazon.com/DocaPole-Extension-Extendable-Ceilings-Telescopic/dp/B07N318K4H/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?crid=10ZLR2ZLLQTS3&keywords=tall%20light%20bulb%20changer&qid=1581030413&sprefix=tall%20light%20bulb%20chan%2Caps%2C160&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExUENEWEpSRjNXNTRYJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMjUxMTMzVDU4MFJIOEgxTjhYJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTA5NzIzNzQxVklOUjkxUjFMM1ZZJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==) that might work as well.

Comment: These ladders are good for some staircases, but the one in the picture looks like the ceiling is just too high.  OP can take some measurements to be sure.

Comment: If you’re only 3 vertical feet off while on the stairs, the right staircase ladder should easily give you that 3 or 4 foot rise you need.

Comment: @v15 I think you're right, I'm considering buying one of these now.

Comment: @vallismortis I think you’ll be pleasantly surprised at how well it works for a set up like that since you can control how steep of a pitch (angle against the stairs) you’re comfortable working with.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem - I am looking at using 2 little giant ladders and a metal work plank to get up there.  It doesn’t look like fun. I did watch a video were a platform was built in the stairwell and then a ladder placed on that.  Didn’t see fun either...

[image]

([source](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Werner-8-ft-13-ft-Aluminum-Extension-Plank-with-250-lb-Load-Capacity-PA208/100658407?mtc=Shopping-VF-F_D22-G-D22-22_8_LADDERS-Werner_Ladders-NA-Feed-LIA-NA-NA-LADDERS_WernerLadders&cm_mmc=Shopping-VF-F_D22-G-D22-22_8_LADDERS-Werner_Ladders-NA-Feed-LIA-NA-NA-LADDERS_WernerLadders-71700000050527121-58700004942209473-92700042887077266&gclid=EAIaIQobChMImbWGobbF5wIVx0XVCh3YtwUQEAQYAyABEgIWqvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds))

Comment: I hate those ladders (I'd use an extension ladder, with boots on it). But: metal plank, +1

Answer (score 2):

How about coming from above and installing a DIY chandelier lift? See this video about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Xoc6VXUjj4

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This is the way to go. I cheaped out and use a hand cranked lift that only costs 25 dollars.

Answer (score 1):

Most hardware stores sell bulb changing extension poles:
[image: example]

I can't tell from the picture if there is a decorative shroud over the bulb; if there is I would change the light fixture.

I had my GC put 20 year LED puck lights in hard to reach areas in my home (indoor and outdoor). You might consider this too if it fits the rest of the decor.

Comment: Interesting device. I'm planning on replacing the entire fixture, not just the bulb. I'll update my question to clarify this.